# Importing array directly as raster to PostGIS in memory?

Tags: postgis, raster

Below is python code I wrote to import downloaded rasters into a postgis table using raster2pgsql. I have a question involving efficiency.

Instead of writing the raster to disk after doing array manipulations and then importing the written file to postgis, is there a way to directly import the array as a raster to postgis in memory? ie can I skip writing the raster to disk somehow?

I realize raster2pgsql is expecting a filename, but maybe there is a solution that goes straight from the in memory array to an in memory raster to postgis.

```
def write_raster(file_path, rast_array, no_data_value, rast_cols, rast_rows, projection, transform):
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('Gtiff')
    raster = driver.Create(file_path, rast_cols, rast_rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    band.SetNoDataValue(no_data_value)
    band.WriteArray(rast_array)
    raster.SetProjection(projection)
    raster.SetGeoTransform(transform)
    band.FlushCache()

def save_raster_to_postgis(raster_path, table_name):
    new_table = not table_exists(table_name)

    # remove old entry if already exists
    if not new_table:
        query = "DELETE FROM %(table)s WHERE filename = %(filename)s;"
        data = {"table": AsIs(table_name), "filename": os.path.basename(raster_path)}
        curs.execute(query, data)
        conn.commit()

    # insert the raster (either create a new table or append to previously created table)
    if new_table:
        import_command = "raster2pgsql -s 4269 -c -I -C -M -F -t auto {file} public.{table}"
            .format(file=raster_path, table=table_name)
    else:
        import_command = "raster2pgsql -s 4269 -a -M -F -t auto {file} public.{table}"
            .format(file=raster_path, table=table_name)
    import_command2 = "psql -h {host} -p {port} -d {database} -U {user} --no-password"
        .format(host=db["host"], port=db["port"], database=db["db"], user=db["user"])
    ps = subprocess.Popen(import_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    subprocess.check_output(import_command2, stdin=ps.stdout, shell=True)
    ps.wait()


ds = gdal.Open(some_rast_file)
band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
rast_array = band1.ReadAsArray()

# do some manipulations to the array here

write_raster(save_path + file_name + '.tif', temps_array, -9999, 2145, 1377, projection, transform)

save_raster_to_postgis(save_path + file_name + '.tif', 'my_rast_table')
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  If you take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), it will note "Asking one, and only one, important question within your Question helps attract prompt and clear Answers." Please **edit** your Question to contain one question.

Comment: Something else that you may want to pay attention to is presenting just a working code snippet.  That way you will definitely be on-topic.  At the moment I think your question risks being seen as asking for a smallish [codereview.se].

Comment: Give the details of the system you're running the code on.